# Disable Android Studio's automatic layout attributes?

Tags: android, android-layout, autocomplete, android-studio

In Android Studio, autocompleting a layout tag automatically inserts `layout_width` and `layout_height` attributes.

Typing this:

```
<Tex
```

and hitting Enter gives me this:

```
<TextView android:layout_width="" android:layout_height="" />
```

and locks my cursor in the `layout_width` attribute, destroying my typing flow and requiring me to escape and manually format the tag.

These attributes are *required* to be present, and Android Studio is smart enough to say as much, so I'm not even capable of making the mistake they're trying to correct. Is there a way to force autocomplete to insert only the tag name, without attributes?

Comment: I think it might be in File -> Settings -> Intentions somewhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

File -> Settings -> Editor -> Smart Keys -> Uncheck **Automatically insert required attributes**

**However**, you should use `space` instead of pressing `enter` to do the autocomplete as pressing enter would close the tag (unchecking not to insert closing tag didn't work for me in this case).

If using `space` you can also uncheck `Automatically start attribute` depending on your needs. With this checked it will add a `=""` to allow to start typing in an attribute.

[image]

**Edit**

For using the `space` key to autocomplete:

File -> Settings -> Editor -> Code Completion -> Check **Insert selected variant by typing dot, space, etc.**

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. Pressing space instead of enter doesn't trigger autocomplete for me, but that's something I can look at separately and the behavior when hitting enter is sufficient for my needs.

Comment: @AlexanderPrime Ah forgot that isn't set by default! I edited my answer anyway.

Comment: Wow, that's a _lot_ better. AS's defaults are weird.